# Assign Enum names to const variable

Tags: c#, enums

I'm currently trying to assign the names in a particular enum to a string so that I can use it in the help documentation that is output to the console. This is easy enough to do via:

```
public string names = string.Join(", ", Enum.GetNames(typeof(LicenseType)));
```

My problem is that I'm using the [Command Line Parser Library](http://commandline.codeplex.com/), which requires the help text for each option to be specified as an attribute argument (`HelpText`), which must be a "constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type". Example of how `names` would be used:

```
[Option('t', "license-type", Required = true, HelpText = names)]
```

However, when I try and assign the enum names to a `const string` using the above code, the compiler complains that the expression is not constant.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: The error message is telling you *exactly* what you're doing wrong.  You're trying to assign a non-constant value to a constant member.

Comment: I can see that ;) I suppose I should have been more clear in that I want to know if it's possible at all

Comment: While the accepted answer is correct.  Having looked at the code to see if I could implement some better enum automatic functionality, you can look at the wiki and just hand write your usage to get the results you want . http://commandline.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Format-Help-Screen&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: @SteveMitcham Yeah, I woke up this morning and realised the problem was actually pretty easy to solve in that way (I got too fixated on the initial problem heh); see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** This can no be achieved using the [`nameof` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof), albeit only by referencing each object one by one at compile time.

The problem is that even though `enum`s might be compile-time constants, *any* code, including the above code to actually get those names, is *not* constant, since it requires evaluation beyond simply being a primitive. Thus, it is not possible to use an `enum` name in an `Attribute` which expects a `string`.

IF, however, the `OptionAttribute` is not `sealed`, you could define an inherited `Attribute` class which takes a parameter of the desires Enum, and then passes the above code to `base(string)`. Using this `Attribute`, the library should see it as a `OptionAttribute`, even though you've handed it an `enum` value. See the following code:

```
public class EnumHelpTextAttribute // Always postpend the word "Attribute" to an attribute class
                                   // The compiler cleans this suffix when you actually use the Attribute
    : OptionAttribute
{
    public EnumHelpTextAttribute(LicenseType value)
        : base(string.Join(", ", Enum.GetName(typeof(LicenseType), value)))
    {
    }
}
// ...
[EnumHelpText(LicenseType.Restricted)]  // Or some other value in LicenseType...
```

Sadly, it has been noted that the `OptionAttribute` class *is* `sealed`, which prevents inheritors from being created. Being an open-source project however, it is possible to fork the source, unseal the class, and use the above suggestion thusly. As always, document the usage and make a pull request back - this could easily save someone else the trouble one day!

Comment: It's sealed. https://github.com/gsscoder/commandline/blob/master/src/CommandLine/OptionAttribute.cs

Comment: Then this is an examination of how it would be useful if not sealed. Being open source, this could be made to happen with a patch request, but I'll integrate such into my answer

Comment: `HelpText` is not an attribute itself (I _think_, still new to c#), but an argument to an `Option` attribute (see edits to question). Does that make any difference? Would I have to override the `Option` attribute instead?

Comment: Yes, you would override the `OptionAttribute` class instead. I'll update my answer for that

Comment: Shame about the `sealed`-ness... Thanks for the help anyway (great answer and I'll upvote once I have the required rep!). Never not document changes :)

Answer (score 0):

Enums are compile time constants, but **the compiler has no guarantee that a method call to `string.Join` will yield a constant value** because it is being used with an `Enum.GetName`.

As your enum is a compile to constant, you will need to hardcode the values to your attributes.

Answer (score 0):

After sleeping on it last night, the solution was actually pretty obvious (ain't it always the way!): just use string replacement...

```
class Options
{
    private static string LicenseTypeHelp = "License type (" + string.Join(", ", Enum.GetNames(typeof(CompanyLicenseType))) + ").";

    [Option('t', "license-type", Required = true, HelpText = "License type.")]
    public CompanyLicenseType LicenseType { get; set; }    

    [HelpOption('h', "help", HelpText = "Dispaly this help screen.")]
    public string GetUsage()
    {
        string helpText = HelpText.AutoBuild(this, current => HelpText.DefaultParsingErrorsHandler(this, current));
        return helpText.Replace("License type.", LicenseTypeHelp);
    }
}
```